# python list copy: is there a difference between old[:] and list(old)?

Tags: python

```
old = [1, 2, 3]
```

What is the difference between the following two lines (if there is any)?

```
new = old[:]
new = list(old)
```

**Update** I had already accepted ubershmekel's answer but later I've learned an interesting fact: `[:]` is faster for small list (10 elements) but `list()` is faster for larger list (100000 elements).

```
~$ python -S -mtimeit -s "a = list(range(10))" "a[:]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.198 usec per loop
~$ python -S -mtimeit -s "a = list(range(10))" "list(a)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.453 usec per loop
~$ python -S -mtimeit -s "a = list(range(100000))" "a[:]"
1000 loops, best of 3: 675 usec per loop
~$ python -S -mtimeit -s "a = list(range(100000))" "list(a)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 664 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there's a small difference. There was a discussion on this at [/r/python](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/m1zes/python_copying_a_list_the_right_way/) recently after [this blog post](http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list) explained a readability difference, that `[:]` doesn't work with generators and keeps the same type as the original.

Technically, you get the same thing - a brand new list that still points to the same objects. Choose whichever one you like better (although `[:]` is a bit faster). Personally I agree with the blog post that `list(old)` is more readable.

To answer the comment about the specific difference, in python 3.2:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def colon(x):
...     return x[:]
...
>>> def new_list(x):
...     return list(x)
...
>>>
>>> dis.dis(colon)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 BUILD_SLICE              2
             12 BINARY_SUBSCR
             13 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(new_list)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

Why `list(old)` is slower I think is because the slicing mechanism doesn't need to "LOAD_GLOBAL" and "CALL_FUNCTION" on the list constructor, the entire operation is handled in C.

Comment: @MattFenwick `list(x)` requires looking up the global variable `list` and calling a function with one argument. `x[:]` doesn't do either of these so it has less overhead. If it's a long list the difference will be miniscule (and probably insignificant even for a short list).

Comment: readability is sometimes subjective and depends on background. In that blog or another related I read they called a[:] notation 'cryptic'. well...

Comment: `[:]` is most useful when you want to empty a list without rebinding the name, i.e. `old[:] = []`

Comment: Because in same situations `old` may not be the only name bound to that list object, and you want the other names to also see the update.

Comment: I've read the same blog post which was interesting but did not explain  the difference, hence left me dissatisfied. Thanks for the reddit link and the explanation.

Answer (score 6):

If old is not a list, old[:] will be all the elements of old in the same kind of container as old (maybe a tuple or a string), while list(old) will be a list with the same elements.

I.e. if old is the string 'foo', old[:] will be the string 'foo', while list(old) wille be the list ['f', 'o', 'o'].

Comment: thanks, this is relevant, but I asked specifically about the case when `old` is a list (see my first line, `old = [1, 2, 3]`)

Comment: @bpgergo Ok, I took that line as just an example of what old could look like.  Anyway, no harm done, I hope.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the example you give, there is no difference:  both result in a brand new `list` object with the same elements.

In general

- `new = old[:]` will only work with objects that support slices, and `new` will be the same type as old
- `new = list(old)` will work with any iterable, and `new` will be a `list`

Answer (score 0):

If *old* is an array, then both are equivalent.  But if old is some sort of iterator, only the *list()* syntax will work.  For that reason, the second syntax is probably preferable, as it is more general.

Answer (score 0):

`new = old[:]` creates a copy of list `old` using the slice notation and stores it in `new`.

`new = list(old)` casts `old` to type `list`. It is already a list and it is assigned into `new`.

I believe these both give the same result. That is, `new` contains a copy of `old`.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody has yet mentioned that this functional difference between the two; list(a_generator) will work, while a_generator[:] makes no sense:

```
>>> i = iter([1,2,3])
>>> i[:]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'listiterator' object is not subscriptable
>>> list(i)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: thanks, this is relevant, but I asked specifically about the case when old is a list (see my first line, old = [1, 2, 3])